# What does こした mean?

Tags: meaning, words, verbs

In the sentence:

> まあいいや、(列車は)空いているに**こした**事はないし

What does こした mean? Is this 越す or 鼓する or something other?

And does まあいいや mean "well" or "whatever"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first part, こした is the past tense / completed aspect of the verb 越【こ】す.  In your sample text, this is part of a set construction: ～[する]に越【こ】したことはない.

Some dictionary entries:

- [Weblio monolingual Japanese](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AB%E8%B6%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
- [Weblio E↔J](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AB%E8%B6%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
- [Eijiro](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E8%B6%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

For the second part, yes, まあ basically means "well,..." and いいや parses out as basically "I guess it's good".  As a whole, "well, yeah, okay then..."

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I saw ~にこした事はない for the first time. Gonna check it out. Jsho doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: @SkillGG Jisho does have something about it: https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AB%E8%B6%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Comment: Sorry. I had to miss it, when I was searching for it it didn't appear. I don't know why. Now it does :) Maybe I misspelled it. My fault. Again. Thank you!